# How to fill one dataframe rows cells depending on another dataframe rows values with a join?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, querying

sorry if my question is not that clear, I'm not that good when it comes to querying. I think it would be much easier for me to explain with a schema what I want to achieve.

```
#loading dataframes with csv files
cores = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(coreFile)
children = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(childFile)

#gets all attribute types (entire columns values)
childTypes = children.select("AttributeType").distinct().collect()

#creates new column for each child type
redimDF = cores
for childType in childTypes : 
    redimDF = redimDF.withColumn(childType['AttributeType'], lit(0))
```

I have two dataframes within a databricks cluster

The first one, 'redimDF' :

```
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
|PId|SCode|PCode|LOYALTY|OFFER|VF|VENUE|GROUP|MISSION|REGION|GENERIC|
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
|663|  770|   30|      0|    0| 0|    0|    0|      0|     0|      0|
|527|  786|   32|      0|    0| 0|    0|    0|      0|     0|      0|
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
```

The second one, 'children' :

```
+---+--------------+-------+ 
|PId| AttributeType|  Value| 
+---+--------------+-------+ 
|663|        REGION|      6| 
|663|       LOYALTY|      0| 
|663|         OFFER|   0000| 
|663|       MISSION|      D| 
|663|            VF|     77|
|663|         VENUE|  20744|  
|527|        REGION|      4| 
|527|       LOYALTY|      0| 
+---+--------------+-------+
```

And I want the result to be like that :

```
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
|PId|SCode|PCode|LOYALTY|OFFER|VF|VENUE|GROUP|MISSION|REGION|GENERIC|
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
|663|  770|   30|      0| 0000|77|20744|    0|      D|     6|      0|
|527|  786|   32|      0|    0| 0|    0|    0|      0|     4|      0|
+---+-----+-----+-------+-----+--+-----+-----+-------+------+-------+
```

Is there a way using a pyspark query to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems what you want is `pivot` on the second dataframe and then join the result with the first one. Check [this resource](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html) to see how to do pivot.

Comment: @AllaTarighati in need, I only needed to pivot the second one and do a simple join. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way by using pivot:

1. Create the required dataframes

   ```
   import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
   redim = [(663,770, 30, 0, 0, 0), (527,786, 32, 0 ,0 ,0)]
   redimDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(redim, ["PId","SCode","PCode","LOYALTY","OFFER","VF"])
   redimDF.show()
   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+
   |PId|SCode|PCode|LOYALTY|OFFER| VF|
   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+
   |663|  770|   30|      0|    0|  0|
   |527|  786|   32|      0|    0|  0|
   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+

   children = [(663,"LOYALTY",40),(663,"OFFER", 20),(527,"LOYALTY",40),(527,"VF", 20)]
   childrenDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(children, ["PId","AttributeType","Value"])
   childrenDF .show()
   +---+-------------+-----+
   |PId|AttributeType|Value|
   +---+-------------+-----+
   |663|      LOYALTY|   40|
   |663|        OFFER|   20|
   |527|      LOYALTY|   40|
   |527|           VF|   20|
   +---+-------------+-----+
   ```
2. Pivot childrenDF and when not all attributeTypes of redimDF are in childrenDF, add and set to 0.

   ```
   childrenDF = childrenDF.groupBy("PId").pivot("AttributeType").agg(F.sum(F.col("Value")))
   for col in redimDF.columns:
       if col not in childrenDF.columns:
           childrenDF = childrenDF.withColumn(col, F.lit(0))
   ```
3. Select columns in same order as redimDF and union

   ```
   childrenDF = childrenDF.select(redimDF.columns)
   df = redimDF.union(childrenDF)
   ```
4. groupby and sum to get resulting df

   ```
   df = df.groupBy("PId").agg(F.sum("SCode").alias("SCode"), 
   F.sum("PCode").alias("PCode"), F.sum("LOYALTY").alias("LOYALTY"), 
   F.sum("OFFER").alias("OFFER"), F.sum("VF").alias("VF"))
   df.show()

   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+
   |PId|SCode|PCode|LOYALTY|OFFER| VF|
   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+
   |663|  770|   30|     40|   20|  0|
   |527|  786|   32|     40|    0| 20|
   +---+-----+-----+-------+-----+---+
   ```

Comment: Thanks @fathomson, a simple pivot and a join did the job.